# How to model mongodb for custom user data

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I'm developing a cms using MongoDb and am trying to get some modelling advice.  It's multi-tenant and each tenant can create their own schema and choose what custom fields they want searchable/indexed.  The only thing I'm waffling on is how to model my collections.  It seems to me like it would be ideal for each tenant to have their own collection due to indexing, but I am not very experienced with MongoDb and would love to hear if that's even a valid statement or not.

I'm thinking about separating each tenant's schema definitions from their data - perhaps a customSchema and customData collection for each tenant. Maybe something like customSchema_5543e1191a85d8946f0ee6fc and customData_5543e1191a85d8946f0ee6fc?  The major question here being how many collections are feasible in MongoDb.  I'm not clear if there's a cap with the new WiredTiger or not.  If not, would such a large number of collections have any downsides?

Or, is it better to have just two collections with all tenant's data in them, along with all of their individual indexes?  What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome, particularly if anyone has had experience doing something like this before.

**Update:**
My use case is a cms where tenants can specify their own data, like in Sharepoint or Expression Engine, or most other content apis, like contentful or CloudCMS.  A user can say, "I want to store Products, and each product has a Name, Description, Quantity, and a price".  Another user could say, "I want to store bands, and each band has a Name, a HomeCity, and a whatever."  The users would then want to retrieve and display that data on their pages however they like.  It's a basic cms scenario where tenants can create their own schema, then create, edit, and retrieve entries of those schemas.  Tenants would need to be able to denote which fields they can search on, so this highly customizable indexing per tenant is the primary area of focus and concern in the modelling strategy.

I'm waffling between two big collections to store schemas and data, shared by all tenants, and a pair of those collections for every tenant.  I just don't know the pros and cons of each of those solutions in MongoDb.  I'm also open to any ideas I haven't thought of yet :)

Comment: As always with modeling for MongoDB, it heavily depends on your use cases. Please describe them as exactly as possible (use the edit button) – and while you are at it, please indent your code using 4 more spaces. ;)

Comment: Not sure what more I can say, but I did add a bit more explanation.